Establishing an IPsec IKEv2 VPN connection fails with "IKE failed to find valid machine certificate." on Windows 11
I'm trying to setup a remote access VPN server with IPSec/IKEv2 for a medium sized company. Users are expected to be connecting to this server (a FortiGate firewall) using the native Windows client and are expected to authenticate with certificates.
I struggled for a few days with OpenSSL to generate adequate certificates (CA, server and user certificates) and ended up using EasyRSA with this tutorial.
I installed the certificates on the respective endpoints :

Windows client : CA and user certificates (in both local user & computer certificate stores)
FortiGate server : CA and server certificates

I then configured the Windows native VPN client to match the phase 1 and phase 2 connection parameters with this command :
Set-VpnConnectionIPsecConfiguration -ConnectionName "TEST" -AuthenticationTransformConstants SHA256128 -CipherTransformConstants AES256 -PfsGroup ECP384 -EncryptionMethod AES256 -IntegrityCheckMethod SHA256 -DHGroup ECP384

Unfortunately when trying to establish the connection, it fails with this error :
IKE failed to find valid machine certificate. Contact your Network Security Administrator about installing a valid certificate in the appropriate Certificate Store.

And the Event Viewer shows this :
CoId={FDAC14F2-F462-0004-73CA-ADFD62F4DA01}: The user COMPANY\name dialed a connection named TEST which has failed. The error code returned on failure is 13806.

Which led me to this blog post but I didn't manage to resolve the issue. I suspect there's something wrong with the certificates because when trying to authenticate with a PSK it works fine.
Thank you for help.
EDIT

The user certificate is in the Current User > Personal > Certificates store.
The CA certificate is in the Current User > Trusted Root Certification Authorities > Certificates store.

I've also added the certificates in the same stores but as Local Computer certificates instead of Current User certificates but it doesn't appear to be doing anything whatsoever.
EDIT
The certutil store My command yields this :
================ Certificate 3 ================
Serial Number: 8ed884d983324ca3578e5f7bff425654
Issuer: CN=MyRootCA
 NotBefore: 20/08/2024 10:34
 NotAfter: 23/11/2026 10:34
Subject: CN=tgerber, S=Ile-de-France, C=FR
Non-root Certificate
Cert Hash(sha1): 1cdb0b49e198202896ecff0ca325687e4d3118ed
No key provider information
Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption.


Contact your Network Security Administrator about installing a valid certificate in the appropriate Certificate Store. What store is the certificate in? What are the details of the certificate?

@GregAskew Hello, thanks, I have updated the post. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "details of the certificate" and how can I provide you this information.

Double click on the certificate. It shows most of the details on the first screen, and you can click on the certificate buttons for additional details. I believe you can also use certutil -viewstore store name s/n

I'm fairly certain that CA certificates should not be in the user store, nor should anything trust a CA certificate in the user store.

"The client certificate you want to use must be exported with the private key, and must contain all certificates in the certification path." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-vpn-client-certificate-windows-native

@GregAskew Alright, thank you. I edited the post with the user certificate information and indeed, it is written Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption. which makes me think that there's something wrong with the way I generated the certificate. I'm going to see if I can combine the certificate and the private key in the same file.

Typically certificate generation on Windows involves two certreq command line commands, request and fulfillment. The output is a pfx file, which is a container for the public and private keys and additional certificates. Could also be a .p12 file.

@GregAskew Well, I managed to partially solve the issue thanks to your help. In fact, I generated a .p12 client certificate and put it in the Local Machine store. That allowed me to connect to the VPN server with FortiClient specifying the user certificate. But whenever I try with the native Windows client, it keeps on showing me the same error. Maybe I need to reboot? I'm going to investigate further... maybe I'm missing something else. Also, what's wrong with having a CA certificate in the user store in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder?
